# After update monitor is saying "current timing does not match"

Tags: display, display-resolution

I have a dell system with dell monitor. After updating ubuntu monitor is saying "Current timings do not match. Please change to 1920*1080 60Hz. When I connect this monitor to other systems it works fine. When this cpu is connected to other monitors they can show display. And in the display settings they show 1080p 60Hz. But this system with 1st mentioned monitor is not working.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please edit and add information; version of Ubuntu and the model name of Dell computer.